# can i persist change, when modifying css from the element panel (chrome dev tool)

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

In chrome dev tool, I have done a mapping with resource file.
But when doing a change in the  panel instead of source panel, changes are not persisted... Is it posible to do that ?

I am using polymer (web-compoenent) and the css is in a html document... It would be perfect to have this funcionality with chrome... I have discovered this : http://livestyle.io/ (EMMET) but I use mainly Atom... so maybe there is a better issue.

Comment: Is the source of CSS rule in your file or somewhere else like Inspector stylesheet?

Answer (score 0):

You can inject a CSS file or code into the page. [More info](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts)

Or you can use a chrome extension as [stylebot](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylebot/oiaejidbmkiecgbjeifoejpgmdaleoha) for do it

Comment: I am not sure it does the trick... I need to persists theses changes in my web-component file for example.

Comment: Do you try stylebot?